# swipe to delete & moving cell in UItableView option together in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, edit

I have an issue in editing of TableViewCell. Issue is that client want "Swipe to delete" & "Move cell" option together without iOs showing delete button on cell left side.
Here is my working code
I set

```
[MyTableView setEditing:YES animated:NO];
```

& due to this I am able to hold & to move cell. Now client want that there should not be any button on left side & user should be able to delete cell on swipe action. Now how can I hide this right button while moving cell & enable swipe to delete on cell while table editing style is set to "YES".

Comment: HOw did you do  it

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial, it has sample code also in the end. I have given the link below.

[Clear app tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21842/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-13)